# Backbone Event is firing on parent's View

Tags: events, view, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js I love it so far, I've been using Require.js to modularize the whole project. So far so good, but I do run into some hiccups with the event binding.

Basically what I'm trying to do, when you first go into register page, the router will render the registerView. Inside the register View, you will be presented with a link, I will add more buttons later once I got this one to work.

When the link is clicked, I fire up the showLogin event and call showLogin function, and render login view into the div (#login-container). I can not use `$(this.el).html(template(data));` for some reason. But I get around it by using jquery selector to load the view into the correct div. Can someone explain to me why the `$(this.el` does not work in `login.js`?

Now the main problem, I want to fire another event, when someone click on the Login button. I thought I could fire the event within the loginView(Login.js), but the event was triggered at parent view (Register.js) instead. When I click the button, the javascript console will print:

```
Register.js Login Clicked
```

Since I'm fairly new to this new Framework, there must be something that I forgot to add or maybe I'm doing things incorrectly. I'm hoping from the more experience users to point my mistake. Any ideas?

## index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

## login.html

```
<div id="signin">  
  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Login</legend>
      <input id="login" type="button" value="Login">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

## register.html

```
<ul>
  <li id="login-li"><a id="showlogin">I already have an account</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="login-container">
</div>
```

## router.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'views/register'

  ], function($, _, Backbone, registerView){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      "register": "registerView"
    },

    registerView: function() {
      registerView.render();
    }
  });

  return AppRouter;
});
```

## login.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/login.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, loginTemplate){

  var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#login-container"),
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods
    },

    events: {
      "click input#login":  "login"
    },

    render: function(){
      var data = {};
      var template = Handlebars.compile(loginTemplate);
      $("#login-container").html(template(data));

      #
      # Why the following code does not work like in register.js?
      # $(this.el).html(template(data));
      #

    }, 

    login: function() {
      console.log("Login.js Login Clicked");
    }

  });
  return new loginView;
});
```

## register.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/login',
  'views/signup',
  'text!templates/register.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, loginView, signupView, registerTemplate){

  var registerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#content"),

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },

    events: {
      "click a#showlogin":  "showLogin",
      "click input#login": "login",
    },

    render: function(){
      var data = {};

      var template = Handlebars.compile(registerTemplate);
      $(this.el).html(template(data));
    },

    showLogin: function() {
      loginView.render();
    },

    login: function() {
      console.log("Register.js Login Clicked");
    }
  });
  return new registerView;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize loginView before there is a DOM element with id `#login-container` (added only when the registerView is *rendered*) in the DOM tree, so naturally things go a bit haywire.

What you can do to correct this situation is not to return an instance of each view in their respective modules like this `return new xView`, but instead return the 'class' like this `return xView` and then initialize them when needed like this

```
showLogin: function() {
  (new loginView()).render();
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not make any difference.

Comment: change `el: $("#login-container")` to `el: "#login-container"`. The el variable is not for jQuery objects, there is a separate `$el` for that, but you shouldn't set it by yourself.